# Geodjango create a new SRID

Tags: django, python-3.x, geodjango

Hello guys I've been trying to add a shapefile but I'm facing some difficulties since my country's coordinate system isn't part of the gdal library. How can i create a new SRID.I have already created the srs and defined the spatial reference system in postgis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS stores Spatial reference systems in a table called [`spatial_ref_sys`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ch04.html#spatial_ref_sys). Django has a model to access the data in this table called `SpatialRefSys`, but it's not documented.

Also not documented is the utility function [`add_srs_entry()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d7b2aa24f75434c2ce50100cfef3586071e0747a/django/contrib/gis/utils/srs.py#L5), which takes an [`SpatialReference`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#spatialreference) instance as first argument, which can be defined from a PROJ.4 string.

So something like this should work:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils.srs import add_srs_entry
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import SpatialReference

srs = SpatialReference('''...PROJ.4 string...''')
add_srs_entry(srs)
```

Alternatively, you can add the entry using a database management tool

Comment: GDAL_ERROR 6: b'EPSG PCS/GCS code 7392 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?'

Comment: If I use http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7392/prettywkt/, with an `AUTHORITY["EPSG", "7392"]` field added, I get a `SRSException: Unsupported SRS.` when calling `srs.validate()`. Not sure what's going on here, but apparently, the definition is not valid.

Comment: I solved it, i just went under library share and included my proj4 code under the epsg libraries and it worked. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, @GentBytyqi I am facing the same issue. `GDAL_ERROR 6: b'EPSG PCS/GCS code 99221 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?'` 
can you please guide me how do you add srs in library?

Answer (score 0):

If your country SRID is not supported by GDAL - or **if you want to add your own reference system** - I was able to achieve this using postGIS by adding an entry in `public.spatial_ref_sys` either manually:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.spatial_ref_sys (srid, proj4text) VALUES
($srid, $proj);
```

or with django by getting the table:

```py
from django.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, connections

database = DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
SpatialRefSys = connections[database].ops.spatial_ref_sys()
SpatialRefSys.objects.create(srid=$srid, proj4text=$proj)
```

Have in mind that **you won't be able to transform [GeosGeometry objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#geosgeometry)** as this uses GDAL (which does not read `spatial_ref_sys`). Instead use the [database function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#transform) as follow:

```py
model.objects.annotate(position_wgs84=Transform('position', 4326))
```